# How can I find out if a instance of an assembly is suppressed?

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus

I have an assembly with multiple instances. I want to find out if a specific instance is suppressed. I assume the property is stored somehwere in the instance opbject:

```
instance = mdb.models['MODELNAME'].rootAssembly.instance['INSTANCE NAME']
```

But I can't find the variable that tells me if the instance is suppressed.  Anybody here knows?

I know how to suppress and resume an instance but i don't know what variable is changed when I do that. I think i need to find this variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke I figured it out. You need to do the following.

```
#create a list containing the keys of the instances in the assembly
instance_keys = mdb.models['MODEL NAME'].rootAssembly.instances.keys()
 
#check if the instance is supressed
for key in instance_keys:
    if mdb.models['MODEL NAME'].rootAssembly.features[key].isSuppressed():
        print('Instance: ' + key + ' is supressed')
```